# How to replace a number within a string by itself + 1?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, backreference

I have a string like *"We have a foobar which can provide a maximum of 20 foo per bar."* I would like to replace every occurrence of *"a maximum of "* + a number of any length with `<number++`. The aforementioned string would result in:

> "We have a foobar which can provide <21 foo per bar."

I tought of something like:

```
string.replace("/maximum\sof\s\d+/ig", `<${$1++}`)
```

But I can't get it to work as $1 only backreferences to the entire capture group and not the single number. I also struggle with the string formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback function and capture group

```
maximum\sof\s(\d+)
```

- `maximum\sof\s` - Match `maximum of`
- `(\d+)` - Match one or more digits ( capture group 1)

---

In callback we can use captured group to replace with whatever extra we want

```js
let str = "We have a foobar which can provide a maximum of 20 foo per bar."
let replaced = str.replace(/maximum\sof\s(\d+)/ig, (_, g1) => '<' + (+g1+1))

console.log(replaced)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace can use a function:

```js
let input = "We have a foobar which can provide a maximum of 20 foo per bar.";

console.log(
  input.replace(/(?:\ba )?maximum of ([0-9]+)\b/, function (all, max) {
    return "<" + (max / 1 + 1);
  })
);
```

This matches [`/(?:\ba )?maximum of ([0-9]+)\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/rgmFaQ/2) (with optional leading word-break and `a` ) and then runs a function on the results: the whole match (which we don't use) and then the number. We can then stitch together that segment with the revised number. I'm dividing by one in order to ensure `max` is treated as a number (it'd otherwise be a string, thus concatenating to `201` instead of `21`).